# Ordering an array of negatives, zero and positives integers with one iteration

Tags: code-golf, number, sorting, array

Take an array of integers containing negative numbers, positive numbers and zeros. Group it **with one iteration and in place** such that all of the negative numbers come first, followed by all of the zeros, followed by all of the positive numbers.

Example:

```
Input:  5, 3, 0, -6, 2, 0, 5
Output: -6, 0, 0, 3, 2, 5, 5
```

Note that the numbers do not need to be fully sorted: just sorted by sign.

So, the final array will look like this: `-, -, ..., -, -, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, +, +, ..., +, +`

#### Rules

- You may only use the input array and a constant amount of additional memory (i.e. you may not create any more arrays)
- You may only use one loop, which may execute only as many times as the length of the array. You may not use built-in functions which conceal any kind of loop. This includes built-in sort functions.
- The result should be in the format I described

The winner will be the person who will submit the shortest code (counted in bytes) that changes the initial array into a correct format (like described above).

Comment: Aka the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thx, now I understand what is the task!

Comment: Exactly this http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/504/stable-positive-negative-separation/42723 other than the use 1 iteration and 1 array limit.

Comment: Built-in sort functions are not allowed, right?

Comment: Is sorting by value not allowed or just not necessary?

Comment: @KSFT If the values are sorted by value, it's not a wrong answer supposing there is one iteration in array.

Comment: @KSFT Calling `sort(...)` is not fine since it probably does more than one iterations.

Comment: @IonicăBizău can you specify the exact output for input `[-1, -2, 0, 2, 1]` and if there are more than 1 outputs possible ?

Comment: @Optimizer `[-1, -2, 0, 2, 1]`, `[-2, -1, 0, 2, 1]`, `[-1, -2, 0, 1, 2]`, `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]` Any of these results is correct.

Comment: @Optimizer I don't think it has to be constant space, and you only need to group the elements by sign, not sort.

Comment: @Optimizer It doesn't matter. It should be one iteration, and the result should be in `-...0...+` format.

Comment: @Optimizer, yes.

Comment: Is iterating the array a constant number of times okay?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes for which comment ?

Comment: @Optimizer, the most recent one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, that is not even possible :) . But since this is not pure sorting, it should be possible at least.

Comment: @Optimizer, the canonical solution is linked from the first comment.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I meant sorting an array in linear time and constant space.

Comment: @Optimizer,  No.

Comment: @Optimizer It was a joke, because you asked a bunch of questions and got a reply that just said "yes", but I guess it didn't work because of all the comments in between. I need to refresh more, I guess.

Comment: Is this challenge even possible?

Comment: @Ypnypn Yes, see the algorithm from the Wikipedia page (linked in the first comment).

Answer (score 3):

## C, 92

This could probably be reduced by at least 10 bytes; there are many expressions going to waste.

The first argument should point to the beginning of the array; the second should point after the end of the array.

```
*x;f(b,e)int*b,*e;{for(x=b;x<e;x++)*x>0&&--e-x?*x--^=*e^=*x^=*e:*x<0?b-x?*x^=*b=*x:0,b++:0;}
```

Ungolfed with random test generator:

```
*x;
f(b,e)int*b,*e;{
    for(x=b;x<e;x++) {
        if(*x<0) {
            if(b == x)
                b++;
            else
                *b++ = *x, *x=0;
        } else if(*x>0 && x != --e) {
            *x^=*e^=*x^=*e;
            x--;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[999];
    srand(time(0));
    int n = rand() % 50;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i] = rand() % 9 - 4);
    f(a, a+n);
    puts("");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in Code Blocks and it does not compile, there are 3 errors. What you compiled with? x* is not defined and you made variables before {.

Comment: @bacchusbeale You can compile it with gcc in the default (C89) mode. CodeBlocks isn't a compiler so I can't tell which compiler you are using, but it works with gcc. The reason it may not work with all compilers is K&R-style declarations, which don't comply with the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 1):

### STATA 242

Follows the wikipedia page exactly. Thanks @PeterTaylor

Takes input as a space separated set of numbers from std in and outputs as such as well to std out.

```
di _r(a)
token $a//converts to array (kind of)
loc i=0
loc j=0
loc q=wordcount($a)
loc n=`q'-1
while `j'<=`n' {
loc t=``j''
if `t'<0{
loc `j'=``i''
loc `i'=`t'
loc ++i
loc ++j
}
else if `t'>0{
loc `j'=``n''
loc `n'=`t'
loc --n
}
else
loc ++j
}
//used only to output
forv x=1/`q'{
di ``x'' _c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2: 116 bytes

```
a=input();i=j=0;n=len(a)
while j<n:b=a[j];r,s=b<0,b>0;c=i*r+n*s-s+j*(b==0);a[c],a[j]=b,a[c];i+=r;n-=s;j+=b<1
print a
```

This is a golfed Python translation of the Dutch national flag pseudo-code.

## Possible 112 bytes

Not sure, if this is allowed. It creates a second array of size 3 (constant amount of additional memory!).

```
a=input();i=j=0;n=len(a)-1
while j<=n:b=a[j];k=(i,j,n)[cmp(b,0)+1];a[k],a[j]=b,a[k];i+=b<0;n-=b>0;j+=b<1
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

## C,90

Straightforward implementation of the algorithm in the wikipedia article per Peter Taylor's comment on the question.

Expects to find the data in an array called `a` like the other C answer. `n`,`p` and `z` are pointers for the insertion of negative and positive numbers and zeroes. `n` and `p` are taken as arguments pointing to the first and last elements of the data.

```
f(n,p){int t,z;for(z=n;p-z;z++)(t=a[z])?a[z]>0?a[z]=a[p],a[p--]=t:(a[z]=a[n],a[n++]=t):0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 157 Bytes

Takes the numbers as space separated or comma separated set from 
a prompt dialog and returns the result with a alert dialog.

```
for(v=prompt().split(/,?\s+/),s=function(j,n){t=v[j],v[j]=v[n],v[n]=t},i=j=0,n=v.length-1;j<=n;)
!(~~v[j]<0&&!s(i++,j++)||~~v[j]>0&&!s(j,n--))&&j++;alert(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol - <s>149</s> <s>142</s> 140

```
a: to-block input i: j: 1 n: length? a while[j <= n][case[a/:j < 0[swap at a ++ i at a ++ j]a/:j > 0[swap at a j at a -- n]on[++ j]]]print a
```

This is a direct port of the Dutch national flag wikipedia pseudocode.  Below is how it looks ungolfed:

```
a: to-block input
i: j: 1
n: length? a

while [j <= n] [
    case [
        a/:j < 0 [swap at a ++ i at a ++ j]
        a/:j > 0 [swap at a j at a -- n]
        on       [++ j]
    ]
]

print a
```

Usage example:

```
rebol dutch-flag.reb <<< "5 3 0 -6 2 0 5"
-6 0 0 2 3 5 5
```

NB. Rebol arrays (blocks) don't use commas - `[5 3 0 -6 2 0 5]`

And if its OK wrap this up into a function which takes an array and modifies it in place then we can get it down to 128 chars:

```
>> f: func[a][i: j: 1 n: length? a while[j <= n][case[a/:j < 0[swap at a ++ i at a ++ j]a/:j > 0[swap at a j at a -- n]on[++ j]]]n]

>> array: [5 3 0 -6 2 0 5]
== [5 3 0 -6 2 0 5]

>> print f array
-6 0 0 2 3 5 5

>> ;; and just to show that it as modified array

>> array
== [-6 0 0 2 3 5 5]
```

In fact if didn't need to return array (ie. just modify) then you could shave off 1 more char.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (146)

```
function f($s){for($i=0,$n=count($s)-1;$j++<=$n;)if($k=$s[$j]){$l=$k>0?n:i;$x=$s[$$l];$s[$$l]=$k;$s[$j]=$x;$k>0?$n--|$j--:$i++;}echo print_r($s);}
```

http://3v4l.org/ivRX5

PHP's relatively verbose variable syntax is a bit painful here...

Answer (score 0):

### C++

Un-golfed solution: n counts the negatives added to front of array.
For each element if negative swap with element at n, if zero swap with element at n+1 else swap with last element.

```
void p(int* k,int n)
{
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cout<<*(k+i)<<' ';
}
cout<<endl;
}

void s(int *x,int i,int j)
{
int t=*(x+j);
*(x+j)=*(x+i);
*(x+i)=t;
}
void f(int *x,int L)
{
int n=0;
int k;
for(int i=1;i<L;i++)
{
k=*(x+i);
if(k<0)
{
s(x,i,n);
n++;
}
else if(k==0)
{
s(x,i,n+1);
}
else if(k>0)
{
s(x,i,L-1);
}
}
}

int main()
{
int x[]={5,2,-1,0,-2,4,0,3};
f(x,8);
p(x,8);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam - <s>72</s> 67

```
q~_,(:N;{_U=:B0>{U1$N=tNBtN(:N;}{B{U1$T=tTBtT):T;}{}?U):U;}?UN>!}gp
```

Input: `[5 3 4 0 -6 2 0 5]`
Output: `[-6 0 0 4 2 3 5 5]`

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

**Explanation:**

This is another implementation of the algorithm from wikipedia, using `T` for `i` and `U` for `j` (both automatically initialized to 0).

```
q~                    read and evaluate the array (let's call it "A")
_,(:N;                keep A on the stack and set N ← size of A - 1  
{                     do...  
    _U=:B             keep A on the stack and set B ← A[U] (also leaving B on the stack)  
    0>{               if B > 0
        U1$N=t        A[U] ← A[N]
        NBt           A[N] ← B
        N(:N;         N ← N - 1
    }{                else
        B{            if B ≠ 0
            U1$T=t    A[U] ← A[T]
            TBt       A[T] ← B
            T):T;     T ← T + 1
        }{            else (do nothing)
        }?            end if
        U):U;         U ← U + 1
    }?                end if
UN>!}g                ...while not (U > N)
p                     print representation of A
```